# Find a string in R and replace it with other?

Tags: r

I have this data :

```
  structure(list(bin = structure(1:6, .Label = c("90", "54", 
 "89", "87", "56", "24"), class = "factor"), 
variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ghfg", 
"kl", "MIRO", "SM1"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(81, 0.1, 0.22, 9, 79, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to find the word the contains the following and replace with in the column variable:

```
  te=c(IRO,fg)
```

so  ghfg  will be fg  and MIRO will be IRO

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are lots of functions in many different packages for string replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an edited solution using `stringr` that "ghfg will be fg and MIRO will be IRO", you can add as many other replacements as you need to between "pipe symbols.

```r
library(stringr)

te=c("IRO|fg")

df$new_variable <- 
   ifelse(stringr::str_detect(df$variable, te),
          stringr::str_extract(df$variable, te),
          as.character(df$variable))



df
#>   bin variable value new_variable
#> 1  90     ghfg 81.00           fg
#> 2  54       kl  0.10           kl
#> 3  89     MIRO  0.22          IRO
#> 4  87      SM1  9.00          SM1
#> 5  56     ghfg 79.00           fg
#> 6  24     ghfg   NaN           fg
```

Your data

```r
df <- structure(list(bin = structure(1:6, .Label = c("90", "54", 
                                               "89", "87", "56", "24"), class = "factor"), 
               variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ghfg", 
                                                                          "kl", "MIRO", "SM1"), class = "factor"), 
               value = c(81, 0.1, 0.22, 9, 79, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                    6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks this is nice. But I actually I have lots of words so will be difficult to write each one  here "ghfg" = "fg" and replace. I need to look for the words that contain for instance fg and replace.

Comment: Hmmm not completely sure I understand but see my edit...